# Why Font looks differ browser to browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

Why there is so much difference in the way the fonts looks in different browsers?  I'm using the same css (css3) and same font (Source Sans Pro).  Following are the screenshots for better definition:

### Firefox Image

[image: Firefox Image 1]

### Chrome Image

[image: Chrome Image 1!]

### Firefox Image

[image: Firefox Image 2]

### Chrome Image

[image: Chrome Image 2]

You can see a lot of difference in there, text is much clear in firefox, but in chrome it looks pathetic.  Any suggestion on how to make them look exact similar in all different browsers (cross browser)?

Comment: Fonts vary in their rendering between Operating Systems/browsers...that's the way it works, because they aren't actually quite the same. The rendering engine is different to start...

Comment: You could use a service like font-squirrels @font-face embed packager to make sure you are getting the optimized version for each browser. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: @drCord it is tested on same OS

Comment: @Faizan It varies between both browsers and OSes.

Comment: This [article](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/12/17/type-rendering-review-and-fonts-that-render-well/) -from typekit- may be helpful.

Comment: Short answer  (and I've looked into this thoroughly a couple years ago) you just have to deal with it, choose a different font, or go to images. Browsers (& OS's) will not render text consistantly. It sucks.

Comment: One thing that makes the issue *worse* that you can avoid, is applying  font-weights / font-styles to a font which doesn't "natively" support it. Browsers differ in the way they handle this stuff..

Comment: @Zach L that looks like some intelligent answer, yet not enough

Comment: The first difference seems unavoidable; the second one, though, is *really* different. Are you maybe choosing a font weight not provided by your font, and Chrome is defaulting to the bolder one whereas Firefox selects the thinner?

Comment: @minitech I have given font weight of 200

Comment: @Faizan: And your font provides…? Try setting it to 100.

Comment: @minitech - can you provide the link to your font? Assuming its google fonts like this (http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro) you actually have to select the font-sizes you support

Comment: @ Zach L ya thats right

Comment: @Faizan you mean you've explicitly selected all the font-weight/style's you're using? If you provide the actual `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">` and the CSS applied, I could potentially look a bit deeper for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fonts vary by Operation System, and Browser. It is a somewhat complicated process, so I would take a look at this [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/) on why and how fonts are rendered in the OS and Browser. There are plenty of other resources of the web that can offer supplemental information on this topic if that article doesn't offer a in-depth enough answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it would be almost impossible to make them look the same in different browsers (even when running on the same OS)

every browser has a different font rendering strategy (and so does every OS) , it mostly relies on the OS routines to render the font on the webpage, with few things like kerning and ligatures, as well as the application of underline position and thickness,under browser's control, so we cannot expect perfectly identical rendering in all browsers (even on one platform)

you can read more about it here.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

Answer (score 0):

To make them look exactly the same, you could either create your own font and modify it slightly for each browser and use trial and error until they look the same.

Or, a better option, you could use images instead of text.

An even better option I think is to just choose a font that looks good in both.

Comment: First two options are not good, and cant accept the third one.. any other?

Comment: Important note: If you use an image instead of text, it might have negative SEO consequences. Text is also easier to edit than an image.

Comment: Your third option is basically the only good option. The first option just doesn’t work – custom fonts *still* vary between browsers, and you pretty much can’t make them look the same.

Comment: If using images make sure to use `alt` text (for <img>s) or some text-replacement trick (like `text-indent:-999em`) so as you don't lose all your SEO mojo. I think there *are* tools out there that will automatically generate images server-side based on your text (so that fixes the "harder to edit" problem), but really, your best option is to suck it up and choose a font that renders `OK` everywhere you need it to.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `<canvas>` or SVG to make it consistent. To learn about the basics of doing so with canvas [MDN has a good reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas), with SVG MDN [also is a good reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text). Optimally we'd have a better way but this is the only way I know to make it perfectly consistent across browsers without images

As Minitech mentioned in the comments this isn't a SEO problem given you are only replacing what is on the page, e.g. `<canvas>Title</canvas>` when you have "Title" written on the canvas

The issue with this approach, again as Minitech mentioned, the interactivity of it. They both practically produce an image-like result and share the restrictions as such

On a semi side note, [**CanvasPod**](http://canvaspod.io/) is a great tool meant for mobile development that includes allowing fonts to be consistent

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that botch SEO (PS: downvote was not mine)

Comment: @ZachL: Not if you replace text that was originally on the page (the only good way to do it), but it’s still yucky for zooming, selection, styling, interactivity…

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? He definitely seems to be answering OPs question: "how to make them look exact similar in all different browsers". Its not an *idea* approach per se, but it *is* a valid approach

Comment: Minitech is correct. And I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted when this is the only way to make it consistent without an image...

Comment: well, you can probably use Flash (SFIR(?)) or SVG or some other technique with similar results, right?

Comment: SVG with paths would work better than a canvas, but it’s still not selectable, and scaling it can produce worse results than text because of kerning.